# How to call a Furute<null> Function in another classs...?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have created a Future type function and I was not able to call that Function in another class. How can I call the Function

```
Future<Null> logout() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await ` 
   `SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('username', null);

    setState(() {
      name = null;
      isLoggedIn = false;
    });
```

}

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the object of current class in another class and call logout function from there using its object.
ex:-

```
final CalledClass  _calledClass = new CalledClass();

_calledClass.logout();
```

Comment: i guess your function is calling error is somewhere else use print function for printing some text when function is called for ex "function logout is called ". then check on console.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as Lovnish suggested.

```
class A {
  void logout() {
    print('logout called');
  }
}

class B {
  void methodFirst() {
    A a = new A();
    a.logout();
  }
}

void main() {
  B b = new B();
  b.methodFirst();
}
```